# Problemas no retorno de uma Query [Qt MySQL]

Tags: mysql, c++, qt

Considerando a seguinte tabela:

```
ID            : int
Quantidade    : smallint
PrecoUnitario : float(5,2)
```

Testei a seguinte Query no MySQL Workbench:

> SELECT ID, SUM(Quantidade * PrecoUnitario) FROM teste GROUP BY ID;

E como é expectável foi executada corretamente.

Contudo, quando eu faço a implementação em Qt e tento obter os resultados não é possível:

```
    qDebug() << "Correndo Teste...";
    QSqlQuery query(myDB);

    query.prepare(" SELECT ID, SUM(Quantidade * PrecoUnitario) FROM teste GROUP BY ID;");

    if(!query.exec())
        throw "Error";
    else{
        qDebug() << "Size: " << query.size();
        while(query.next()){
             qDebug() << query.value(0).toInt();
             qDebug() << query.value(1).toFloat();
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "Fim!";
```

Isto é, estando a tabela preenchida com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
| 1 | 3 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 3 | 2.00 |
| 2 | 3 | 3.00 |
```

O resultado da implementação é:

> Correndo Teste...
>
> Size: 2
>
> Fim!

Apesar do tamanho retornado ser 2, o ciclo *while* nunca é corrido.
Estranhamente, ao alterar o `PrecoUnitario` para *int* o problema desaparece.

Existe alguma justificação para o que está a acontecer?